# How to automatically run a script once, after installing lubuntu from a pen drive?

Tags: unity, usb, lubuntu, scripts

I've got this usb stick I'll send to my sister, and I couldn't put int Ubuntu in it (just little less than 1 gb and few MB short of fitting in 14.04). So I decided to go with Lubuntu.

Then, I've installed it in 2 machines and noticed how bad it might be for her (and any regular user) to use LXDE, at least compared to unity (side note - as a Unity3D developer myself, I hate how confusing those names became!). And, after long research, found a simple way to install Unity afterwards:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

That's it. I'm writing from it right now! :)

Now, I wanted to add those 2 lines of script to the end of installation, a "run after" script, to my lubuntu pen drive installation as an automated process.

Is there some way to do it?

Or would you recommend another way to go around with this? :P